# How to extract the specific line in HTML file from python?

Tags: python, html-parsing

I want to extract the specific red line of item from the HTML files (10 files).
For example I have a code in the html file :

```
Function A()
{
if ---- "Which is red color"
    {
        Print "Hello" 
    }
else-if
    {
        print "World"
    }
 } "End of function A"

Function B ()
{
    if
    {
        Print "Hello" 
    }
    else-if  ---- "Which is red color"
    {
        print "World"
    }
} "End of function B"'
```

HTML format as :

```
<html>
<!-- This file was generated by ApiDoc++ 2.0 -->
<!-- please do not modify this file -->
<head><meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type"/><title>Sample.html</title></head>
<body>
<br/>
Function <font color="#00A500"> A </font><br/>
<font color="#00A500">{</font><br/>
<br/>
<font color="#FF311D"><u>if</u></font>
<font color="#00A500">{</font><br/>
<font color="#00A500">Print Hello;</font><br/>
!
!
!
!
```

So on ...

Output Need as :

```
Funct A - if
Funct B - else-if
```

I have written a python Program as :

```
def searchhtml(data):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
    for ran in soup.findAll('font', {'color':'#FF311D'}) :
    print ran.text

if __name__=='__main__':
    page = urllib.urlopen('Sample.html').read()
    searchhtml(page)
```

Problem is :
I am getting the output as :

```
if

else-if
```

But I need as

```
Function A - if

Function B - else-if
```

Please help me to get the correct output format .

Comment: That's... not... html... that's a blob of text. You need to parse that text and extract what you want...

Comment: I have added the HTML format as above